# Check whether the value exists in the mongodb database using c# driver 2.4.4

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am querying the mongodb database as following to find a document.

```
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("knowledge");  
        var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Regex("question", "(account)") & builder.Regex("question", "(open)");
        var results = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

If the question is/ are found, I display them in the console. **If nothing is found I want to display that 'Nothing Found'.**  How do I check that here.

I tried

```
if(results == null)
```

and `

```
if (builder.Exists("question", false))
```

http://www.fourthbottle.com/2016/08/not-exists-in-mongodb-with-dotnet-driver.html

the results is in `List<BsonDocument>` type. I am using the driver version 2.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results variable is a list. So you'd want a results.Count == 0 check.